# Drawing a Diagonal Line in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I was wondering if it is possible to draw a diagonal line by using UIViews?  I have successfully made a straight line (vertical/horizontal) but I can not find a way to rotate the line.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a basic example of a view that contains a diagonal line view in Swift 2. When the view's bounds change, the diagonal is adapted by adjusting it's length and the rotation angle.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewWithDiagonalLine: UIView {

    private let line: UIView

    private var lengthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    init() {
        // Initialize line view
        line = UIView()
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

        clipsToBounds = true // Cut off everything outside the view

        // Add and layout the line view

        addSubview(line)

        // Define line width
        line.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))

        // Set up line length constraint
        lengthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        addConstraint(lengthConstraint)

        // Center line in view
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: line, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Update length constraint and rotation angle
        lengthConstraint.constant = sqrt(pow(frame.size.width, 2) + pow(frame.size.height, 2))
        line.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(atan2(frame.size.height, frame.size.width))
    }

}
```

Putting that into a plain view controller for demonstration purposes

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let v = ViewWithDiagonalLine()
        v.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200)
        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        v.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.addSubview(v)
    }

}
```

yields the result

[image: simulator screenshot showing a view with a diagonal line]

Comment: Spectacular and informative answer.  Two quick fixes - line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is not a property...instead change it to be a function and use: line.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false).  Secondly, remove the ? in required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {.  Otherwise it works perfectly! Thank you! :)

Comment: @alex1511 Sorry, I forgot to mention that the code in my answer is for Swift 2. If you want to use it in Swift 1.2 you indeed need those adaptions you mentioned.

Comment: One further question:  This currently only can draw a line that is top left to bottom right...how would I got about doing top right to bottom left?

Comment: @alex1511 Just change the angle calculation to `CGFloat(M_PI) - atan2(frame.size.height, frame.size.width)`.

Comment: One more follow up question!  How can you remove the line once it is drawn... I have tried line1.hidden and even tried removing all the subviews of line1 but nothing appears to work.

Comment: @alex1511 I am not sure what `line1` is in your context but setting `hidden = true` should do it. Alternatively you can remove the line view by calling `removeFromSuperview()`. Are you sure you got the right reference?

Answer (score 0):

You could rotate the `UIView` by setting its `transform` property. You'd want to use `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` or `CGAffineTransformRotate`.

However, you'd probably be better off using a `CAShapeLayer` and setting its `path` property to the line you want to draw.